# Admin and Customer login in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code which attempts to check whether a user is an **admin** or **customer** to login, and then there's one problem I can't solved it. When I use the **customer user's account** to login, for example using redhood as my customer's username to access the customer login page. But when I use the **admin user's account** to login, for example using wolfpack as my admin's username, it redirect me to the customer login page instead of the admin login page. But I don't know which **php code** I need to change. Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks!

**MySql Database:**

[image]

**Signin.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin/signin_desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin/signin_tablet.css" media="screen and (max-width:768px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signin/signin_mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:480px)">

</head>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>

<nav id="mainMenu">
  <img src="logo/logo.png" id="logo">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="rates.html">Booking Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="facilities.html">Recreation</a></li>
  </ul>  
</nav>

</header>


<section id="banner">

    <div id="ritu" class="shadow">
       <img src="images/content_pure.jpg">
       <img src="images/Sports-Hub-Gym.jpg">
       <img src="images/gym.jpg">
       <img src="images/ClubFitt2jpg.jpg"> 
    </div>
</section>


<section id="content">

<div id="sign">
    <div class="user">
      <h2>Existing User</h2>

      <form action="checkuser.php" method="post">
        <p style="color:white;">Username:</p> 
       <input type="text" name="uname" size="25" maxlength="20" placeholder="Please enter your username" required><br><br>
        <p style="color:white;">Password:</p> 
       <input type="password" name="pword" size="25" maxlength="20" placeholder="Please enter your password" pattern=".{6,}" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="">
      </form>

      <?php

      if(isset($_GET['uname']) && isset($_GET['pword']))
      {
          echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username and Password.')</script>";
      }
      ?> 

    </div>

    <div class="user">
      <h2>New User</h2>

      <a href="createacc.html"><img id="create" src="button/CREATE%20ACCOUNT.png"></a>

      <p style="color:white;">Ads:</p>

      <div id="ads">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="image">
              <img id="minilogo" src="logo/logo.png">
                <div id="advt">
                   Download Now
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image">
              <img id="apps" src="images/myActiveSG%20APP.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>   


      </div>
    </div>

</div>


</section>


<footer>

<p>© Copyright 2016 SportLab. All Rights Reserved.</p>   
<nav id="submenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Sitemap &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;| </a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
       <li><a href="term.html">Term of Use  </a></li>
       <li><a href="privacy.html">| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Privacy </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Check Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php


if(isset($_POST["loginbtn"])) 
{
      $u=$_POST['uname'];
      $p=$_POST['pword'];

      $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "M3_156020K_Syahri_SportFacility");
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM create_user WHERE username='" .$u. "' AND password='" .$p. "' ";
      $search_result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

      $userfound=mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

      if($userfound >= 1)
      {
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['MM_Username']= $u; 

           $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_result);

           if($row['role'] == 1)
           {
               header("Location: login_admin.html");
           }
           else
           {
               header("Location: login_cust.html");
           }
      }
      else
      {
           header("Location: signin.html?uname=" . $u . "&pword=" . $p);
      }



  mysqli_close($conn);  

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a framework that takes care of all your ACL issues like [otp-thing by microvb](https://github.com/microvb/otp-thing).  Also, a glaring issue in your code, is you are initializing the session AND trying to change it's value after you have sent output already.

Comment: Plain Text password... Bad idea ...PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @RiggsFolly - also :  trying to initialize sessions after sending output.  Allowing direct input from post to pass to a sql query,  revealing user and pass on redirect.  Redirecting to pages that can't validate users server side (  .html ), and so on.  Hence why I recommended otp-thing as it takes care of all that nasty security stuff including roles.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any  errors to the screen so you cannot miss or ignore.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance, one of the things you should correct, is to not send output until AFTER you have finished working with the session. Also, as [Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475954/3504007) mentioned, you are checking if the field equals 1, and not the actual value in the field.

For example, moving the html block to after your conditions like so ( *Updated this example to use prepared statements* ) :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["loginbtn"])) {
  $u=$_POST['uname'];
  $p=$_POST['pword'];

  $conn=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "" , "M3_156020K_Syahri_SportFacility");
  $sql = "SELECT `role` FROM create_user WHERE username=? AND password=?";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('ss', $u, $p);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($role);
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
  if($role) {
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['MM_Username']= $u; 
       if($role == 'Admin') {
           header("Location: login_admin.html");
       } else {
           header("Location: login_cust.html");
       }
  } else {
       header("Location: signin.html?uname=" . $u . "&pword=" . $p);
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);  
}
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Check Login</title>
</head>

<body>
```

At the end of the day, I would seriously reconsider writing your own login system from scratch especially given the apparent lack of attention to obvious security holes.  I would recommend a package out of the box such as [otp-thing](https://github.com/microvb/otp-thing) or if you must write the whole portal yourself, something like Laravel/etc.

Comment: This thing is still a long, long way from being in a form that any sane person would put on their server. Those SQL injection holes are a huge problem. I know you're trying to help, but ignoring those is like giving a patient suffering a heart attack a pain killer.

Comment: @tadman - I agree, but we aren't here to re-write their code.  If you notice I also suggested a solution to replace their current login system attempt which is much more thorough and covers the plethora of dangers they have in their original code. This 'solution' was merely to address the requested issue - not fix everything wrong with their code methods.

Comment: Fixing the injection hole is like two more lines of code and actually serves to educate rather than just handing someone a canned and hazardous "solution", that's all. Injection bugs and people writing their own crappy login systems are serious problems in the PHP world that can only be rectified with a bit of tough love and leadership.

Comment: @tadman - Again, I agree -- i do disagree that it would be like 2 more lines to fix it properly.  The code is/was a disaster (and I have a splitting headache atm :S).  If you would like to adjust that to not pass the password, read secure password from database, and filter post input, use proper pages for the 'protected' areas, and handle for sql-injection by using prepared statements -- as well as implement csrf tokens to mitigate xss.   You are welcome to.  I strongly suggest he just uses [otp-thing](https://github.com/microvb/otp-thing) instead of trying to correct all that -- much easier!

Comment: `$stmt = $conn->prepare(...)` is basically already there. `$stmt->bind_param(...)` and `$stmt->execute()` are also required. Two more lines and that injection hole is dealt with. Sorry if I sould like a bit of a pedantic jerk, but giving people code they can just cut-paste back into their application can perpetuate bad habits. `otp-thing` is a neat link, though, thanks for that. I know someone looking for such a thing.

Comment: @tadman - not a problem.  the prepared statement partly addresses one of the many holes in that code.  I also agree completely, bad habits are ... bad.  But I kind of gave up trying to fix the world years ago. It's possible the author is just starting out -- or...  doing this for someone.  Maybe it's an internal only system.  I certainly wouldn't use any part of that code for something public facing.  You are welcome for the link also  :) .. will update for the prepared statement example.  Not going further than that tho :S

Comment: @tadman - updated --- as you can see, just for the prepared stuff, more than 2 lines

Comment: That's the ticket. Seeing as how everything gets closed out with the connection, the `close()` parts are mostly redundant but good for a thorough example.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the security issues in the code others have stated, to answer your question...**your condition is wrong**:

`if($row['role'] == 1)` should be changed to `if ($row['role'] == "Admin")`

In your case the role is **never** `1` and therefore will always hit the `else` condition sending them to `login_cust.html`.

Your database roles are only `User` and `Admin`. Change the condition.

Comment: That is true as well -- I overlooked that focusing on the first issue that would be hit which is starting a session after output has been sent.